# syslog message at boot: uninitialized urandom read

Tags: boot, syslog, init-script, random

CPU is [AMD GX-412TC SOC](https://www.amd.com/en/system/files?file=2017-06/g-series-soc-product-brief.pdf):

> GX-412TC GE412TIYJ44JB 4 6W 2MB 1.0GHz/
> 1.4GHz N/A N/A DDR-1333 0-90°C

which does not have `rdrand`:

```
grep rdrand /proc/cpuinfo
# nothing
```

I see following messages in my `syslog` after machine boot:

```
kernel: random: dd: uninitialized urandom read (512 bytes read)
kernel: random: cryptsetup: uninitialized urandom read (32 bytes read)
```

what exactly do these messages mean, and what can I do about it?

Does it mean `dd` and `cryptsetup` try to read from `/dev/urandom`, but there is not enough entropy?

I am using `haveged` daemon, but it is started late in the boot process, after this message appears.

Here is my boot script startup sequence:

```
/etc/rcS.d/S01hostname.sh
/etc/rcS.d/S01mountkernfs.sh
/etc/rcS.d/S02mountdevsubfs.sh
/etc/rcS.d/S03checkroot.sh
/etc/rcS.d/S04checkfs.sh
/etc/rcS.d/S05mountall.sh
/etc/rcS.d/S06bootmisc.sh
/etc/rcS.d/S06procps
/etc/rcS.d/S06urandom
/etc/rcS.d/S07crypto-swap
/etc/rc2.d/S01haveged
/etc/rc2.d/S01networking
/etc/rc2.d/S04rsyslog
/etc/rc2.d/S05cron
/etc/rc2.d/S05ssh
```

the messages in syslog come from these two scripts:

```
/etc/rcS.d/S06urandom  -> dd
/etc/rcS.d/S07crypto-swap -> cryptsetup
```

Should `haveged` be started before `urandom` ?

I am using Debian 10.

Also, I should add that this machine is a bare board, with no keyboard. The only interface is a serial console. I think this has an effect on the available entropy, and is the reason why I have installed `haveged` in the first place. Without `haveged`, the `sshd` daemon would not start for several minutes, because it does not have enough entropy.

Comment: Try to uninstall `haveged` and install what I suggested, it should solve your problem, but I'm specializing on Intel, so I don't know much of AMD. If unsuccessful, you can always revert to `haveged`.

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/buster/rng-tools5

Comment: Sorry, your CPU does not have `rdrand`, in which case my suggestion will likely not help, but you may try it of course if you wish.

Comment: For documentation, it might be helpful to go through this [GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/linuxkit/linuxkit/issues/3096), which explains a lot.

Comment: I found this : https://groups.google.com/g/bigbluebutton-setup/c/RZnQIYKvVJE May help you. (The last answer.)

Comment: /dev/urandom is pseudo random generator and cannot block (even if it runs out of entropy) in contrast to /dev/random. see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89/feeding-dev-random-entropy-pool#7074

Comment: @golder3 - thanks. So what do those syslog messages mean ?

Comment: Apparently dd and cryptsetup are trying to read from /dev/urandom before it has been initialized, but I don't know how or why that happens or what can you do to resolve the issue. Maybe this could be helpful - https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Random_number_generation#/dev/urandom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For haveged to work, it has to be compatible with your kernel — there's an issue with haveged not doing anything in kernel versions >=5.x, see [is haveged still useful/relevant? #57](https://github.com/jirka-h/haveged/issues/57) on GitHub.

The maintainer was kind enough to re-introduce functionality but those patches will have to be released and then make it into the various distros first... the old version either won't start at all or won't actually do anything even if it's running (check with `strace`), as the kernel's entropy pool no longer seems to be lacking — but crng init still takes time for some reason.

It also has to run very early on, so if you are using initramfs, then you also have to start haveged in initramfs, some time before using the random device. In a traditional init system, haveged should run as soon as `/proc` `/sys` `/dev` is available.

I'm not sure how long haveged takes exactly to send entropy to the kernel... it has to harvest randomness on its own first and it runs some quality tests on that too. In my last test (with patched haveged) there was like half a second delay between starting haveged and kernel reporting `random: crng init done`.

In addition to haveged, you can also consider saving/restoring a random seed, and if you have network, a little bit of traffic might help the kernel to collect some entropy as well.

Comment: thank you. I am using custom kernel `5.10.82`, and `haveged` version `1.9.1-7`. Does it mean I have to upgrade `haveged` to latest version?

Comment: @400theCat with haveged 1.9.16 you can use `haveged --once` in initramfs - https://github.com/jirka-h/haveged/releases/tag/v1.9.16 . another alternative (discussed in the github haveged bug #57) might be to use `/dev/random` instead of `/dev/urandom` because for some reason, kernel 5.6+ only uses jitter entropy for the former and not the latter. OTOH `/dev/random` might block, you'll just have to try and see for yourself. Using haveged (and random seed) is my personal preference...

Answer (score 4):

Your diagnosis is correct: a read was attempted on an empty entropy pool. This is "[boot time entropy starvation](https://wiki.debian.org/BoottimeEntropyStarvation)".

You can either leverage systemd-boot if you have an EFI system, **ignore the warning** (you're using a predictable crypto, but in *most* use cases that's still better than no crypto at all), or try crediting entropy from alternate sources - *if available* - adding this to the kernel command line

rng_core.default_quality=X

(start at X=1000 and go down from there).

There are other techniques to collect entropy; a SOC might have some pins available and there are hardware driver modules that allow collecting entropy from them. It is then just a matter of connecting some suitable transistor-and-resistor setup (or in some cases, an electret mic) to gather some thermal noise.

Alternately, the 5.4+ series kernels have a more efficient entropy collection which might be enough.