# Why ubuntu 18 not booting inder vmware?

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, random

Image imported from AZURE and converted to VMWARE. Booting stop after few seconds. Can't understanding why...

Very long loading "random:" and no loading more.
[image]

Comment: Not directly related but you do know you're well past End Of Life for Ubuntu 18 don't you?

Comment: I know, but this vm have very old and very important project. I'm trying to port it to a newer version of the system, but it's not so easy, because of old package dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the kernel messages (and it's a wild guess), it seems like it might be related to RNG (random number generator) device or virtual device (or lack of them), but the information is insufficient to specify what's the problem.

Since you're on vmware, I'd suggest trying changing the VM configuration or attached virtual hardwares. Starting from the configuration similar to original environment (you can try some tools such as `dmidecode`, `lspci`, `lsusb` to find out what virtual/physical hardware are attached to it, if you still have access to the Azure VM) would be a good starting point.

Also, it's not related to the question but consider migrating to newer LTS version of Ubuntu if you can ;)

Comment: I know, but this vm have very old and very important project. I'm trying to port it to a newer version of the system, but it's not so easy, because of old package dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my 5 cents.

The long loading of `random` module may indicate general lack of entropy on host machine.

You may even not have [`rdrand` instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDRAND) in your CPU flags, which you may verify with:

```
grep -m1 rdrand /proc/cpuinfo
```

If you get no result, you do not have [`rdrand` instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDRAND) in your CPU repertoir.

---

Where to get entropy = what to try:

```
$ apt-cache policy rng-tools5 
rng-tools5:
  Installed: 5-4
  Candidate: 5-4
  Version table:
 *** 5-4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

If you find that you do not have `rng-tools5` package installed, then install it right away, AFAIK you need to reboot afterward, but that I never tested not doing.

Final check, if the package managed to gather entropy from somewhere, may look like this:

```
$ sudo rngd -v
[sudo] password for vlastimil:                
Available entropy sources:
    Intel/AMD hardware rng
    DRNG
```

Comment: Experiments showed that the system boots normally in recovery mode.

Comment: flags: ...skipped... f16c rdrand hypervisor ...skipped...

Comment: rngd: read error. Available entropy sources:
 Intel/AMD hardware rng
 DRNG

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [syslog message at boot: uninitialized urandom read](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/675686/100397).

My *guess* is that when booting in the Azure environment there was a random number generator that isn't present in your VMware configuration. I would start by checking the kernel command line boot arguments to see if there is any custom reference to an Azure-related module that is no longer relevant in your new situation.